# Problems building evil library (efl) for posix dependencies in cygwin

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, autoconf, efl

I have a project I'm trying to build using mingw and it's missing some posix dependencies:

http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

Since I don't want to spend the effort porting the sourcecode, I found a library that seems to promise to provide some of the missing posix dependencies:

http://git.enlightenment.org/core/efl.git/

More specifically

http://git.enlightenment.org/legacy/evil.git
(Evil library in efl core)

I am trying to build this library with cygwin, but hitting all sorts of roadblocks with autoconf

Has anyone ever built this library? I really just need the posix dependencies, any idea if i can just download them from somewhere reliable? I just want to get this damn thing to compile...

Update

I figured out enough autoconf stuff enough to get to this point

```
$ sh ./configure
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/home/me/legacyevil/evil':
configure: error: cannot run C++ compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

Using /usr/bin/i686-pc-mingw32-g++.exe

Running ./configure --host=windows I got to

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in'

When I run automake I get

```
configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
doc/Makefile.am:7: error: EFL_BUILD_DOC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
doc/Makefile.am:44: warning: wildcard $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
doc/Makefile.am:44: (probably a GNU make extension)
src/bin/Makefile.am:38: error: EVIL_HAVE_WINCE does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCCAS does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCCAS' is to add 'AM_PROG_AS'
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: AMDEP does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'AMDEP' is to add one of the compiler tests
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:     AC_PROG_CC, AC_PROG_CXX, AC_PROG_OBJC, AC_PROG_OBJCXX,
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:     AM_PROG_AS, AM_PROG_GCJ, AM_PROG_UPC
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
src/bin/Makefile.am: error: Preprocessed Assembler source seen but 'CCAS' is undefined
src/bin/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define 'CCAS' is to add 'AM_PROG_AS'
src/bin/Makefile.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
src/bin/Makefile.am: error: Preprocessed Assembler source seen but 'CCASFLAGS' is undefined
src/bin/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define 'CCASFLAGS' is to add 'AM_PROG_AS'
src/bin/Makefile.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCC' is to add 'AC_PROG_CC'
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
src/lib/Makefile.am:27: error: EVIL_HAVE_WINCE does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
src/lib/Makefile.am:88: error: EVIL_HAVE_WINCE does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
src/lib/Makefile.am:104: error: EVIL_HAVE_WINCE does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
src/lib/Makefile.am:4: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
src/lib/Makefile.am:4:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
src/lib/Makefile.am:4:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
src/lib/Makefile.am:4:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
src/lib/Makefile.am:4:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/arithchk.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake-1.14: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake-1.14: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake-1.14: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake-1.14: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However,
automake-1.14: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will
automake-1.14: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory
automake-1.14: of the corresponding sources.
automake-1.14: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake-1.14: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/dmisc.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/dtoa.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/g_dfmt.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/gdtoa.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/gethex.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/g_ffmt.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/g__fmt.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/gmisc.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/g_xfmt.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/hd_init.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/hexnan.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/misc.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/qnan.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/smisc.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/strtodg.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/strtof.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/strtopx.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/sum.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: warning: source file 'gdtoa/ulp.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/lib/Makefile.am:34: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCXX does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCXX' is to add 'AC_PROG_CXX'
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
```